# Происхождение слова "атас"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

"Атас" на воровском (?) жаргоне означает "тревога". Интересно было узнать, откуда это слово вообще взялось и что изначально означало?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: См. Яндекс/словарь :

attention [ ̃ ̃] 
**внимание**

attention suivie — неослабное внимание

 éveiller l'attention de qn — привлечь, пробудить внимание 

 attirer l'attention de qn sur qch — обратить внимание на 

faute d'attention — по невниманию

fais attention! разг — осторожно!

fais attention que… — смотри, чтобы…

une attention avertie — бдительность

**attention! — осторожно!, берегись!**

attention au commandement! воен — слушай команду!
Французский был в России распространен, так что **атасье** (?) вполне могло попасть в разговорный язык.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Версий, действительно, много. Похожие слова есть во многих языках, а как оно в русский попало - неизвестно.

1. Про "атас" из сайта Одесский сленг:  одесский краевед Олег Губарь:блатной «атас» - это «крик на уток», то есть, таким образом погоняли (отгоняли) домашнюю птицу.   http://www.odessit.ua/news/odessika/7429-odesskiy-sleng-chto-takoe-atas-lichman-i-mokruha.html
        http://odesskiy.com/pro-odesskiy-yazik/odesskie-sleng.html

   - Атас, атас, кагуре, до дому!

   Продам тебе жидовi рудому.

   "Если обратиться к "Словнику дiалектизмiв українських говiрок Одеської областi" (Одесса, 1958 год)  А.А. Москаленко, мы обнаружим, что "атас" и через сто лет оставался в прежней своей семантике: "вигук, яким вiдганяють качок". В криминальном жаргоне оный клич использовался практически по назначению, что нисколько не смущало простодушных селян, и они продолжали, как ни в чем не бывало, привычно "шугать" гусей и уток".
2. "атас" -возм. от устар. диал. межд. «ату», «атата», «ататя», «атати», выражающих досаду.
3. "атас!” происходит от удмуртского атас, то есть ‘петух’. Есть удмуртская сказка про петуха-хулигана, как только его видели, предупреждали об опасности всех.
4. Атас `Словарь иностранных слов`
   [вероятно, от фр. attandez - подождите (метать карты)] - жарг. на воровском жаргоне означает: "Будьте осторожны!", "Внимание, опасность!" Использовавшееся ранее русск. "атанде-с" могло быть сокращено до "атас".
   (Источник: "Словарь иностранных слов". Комлев Н.Г., 2006)

   http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/6142/%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%A1
5. санскр. atas 2. adv. 1) потом, затем 2) потому 3) отсюда, начиная с этого (места, времени)Третье значение как раз и есть русское восклицание "атас", т.е. (ребята, срочно отваливаем) отсюда!
   Но это всё версии. Возможно, что-то совпало в значениях. Иногда так бывает, что слова одновременно приходят из разных языков и совпадают в значениях.

Answer (score 2):

Мои ровесники в 50-е(а жили мы в Туркестане и было нам лет по 6-8) кричали "атАнда!". Став грамотнее, я понимал, что это от французского "attandez" (атандЭ).Слово "атас" я услышал позже, в Сибири и  воспринял как детское сокращение от "атанда". А значение, конечно, было то же, что у блатных - "шухер,смываемся!". Обычные детские выражения - "Ванька - на атасе!" или "на шухере" - назначение наблюдателя, часового.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то в словарях воровского жаргона это слово отсутствует (из того что есть под рукой).

По фене обычно "шухер". "Атас" - это что-то детское.

Но если предположить, что "атас" это все-таки феня, то вероятны иврит корни.

Цитурую с лингвофорума:

Корявцев П.М.

"Отдельные вопросы этимологии блатной фени"
......
атанда
- ивр. "атуд" и производные, букв. "подготовка", "предназначение".
- традиционный возглас-предупреждение, в настоящее время может считаться устаревшим. Возможно отсюда же и "атас".

Вот еще версия.

"Атас" - Сокращенное от татарского атасы, что значит отец кого-либо. Происхождение. Криминальное происхождение слова начинается от детских провинностей. Все мы играли в детстве в игры, бывало так, что играя кого-то обижали, а тот кого обидели мог пожаловаться своему отцу. Сигнал : Атасы, означал отец его идет, что сулило мало добра, все зачинщики потасовок разбегались. А в русский язык слово попало в сокращенном виде, но с тем же смыслом- пора разбегаться, конец игре.

Елистратов допускает уголовное происждение, но в явном виде к фене не относит:

АТАС, межд. 1. Осторожно! Внимание! Бежим! атас, менты! — осторожно, милиция! атас, сюда бежит матрас — шутл. предостережение об опасности (из детск). 2. Выражает любую эмоцию.
Возм. из уг. Ср. комментарии к АТАТУЙ.
См. также ПОЛНЫЙ

http://gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_276

Про "ататуй" же у него сказано следующее:

АТАТУЙ, -я, м. Ситуация, характеризующаяся какими-л. крайностями; крайне необычное положение. В магазине полный ататуй: одна продавщица (ничего нет). В универсаме ататуй: и мясо, и колбаса, и водки леса (всё есть).

Возм. от устар. диал. межд. «ату», «атата», «ататя», «атати», выражающих досаду.

В любом случае подобный слова почти всегда имеют не до конца проясненную, если не совсем темную, этимологию. Поэтому версий может быть очень много.

Answer (score 1):

atas - отсюда, поэтому.

Вроде на санскрите звучит именно так.

Источник: Г.Бюлер «Руководство к элементарном курсу санскритского языка».
Стокгольм, 1923

Answer (score 0):

На иври АТШЛ - вести дознание. Прямой указ на крим. одесский - идут дознаватели- АТАС.
ШХР- искать от ШаХ - бродить прогуливаться. Вполне идет к воровскому поведению.

Answer (score 0):

В старину тюрки, как и все кочевники, воевали только на конях, пешие воины или отсутствовали вообще, или набирались из оседлых народов. В казахском языке есть слово "аттан" - это команда, означающая "на коней!" или "по коням!" (от "ат" - конь, "тан" - суффикс), применялась в основном при приближении врагов к военному лагерю или аулу. Из истории мы прекрасно знаем, что воины-тюрки присутствовали везде - в Китае, Индии, Иране, в странах Ближнего Востока, Северной Африки и, конечно же, на просторах Евразии, доходя до Западной Европы. При этом естественно шел взаимообмен как на культурном уровне, так и в языковом. Вполне возможно, что "аттан"-"attan"-"atten"-"attention" сохранилось во французском в значениях "внимание", "осторожно", а в дальнейшем при завоевании бриттами и норманами англосаксков перешло в английский (в английском как известно до 70% французских слов). Ну и из французского, во времена когда он был в моде в России, уже перешел в разговорный русский в виде "атас" от "attention au .." (атасьё). 
Это лишь моя версия и я могу ошибаться, но странно, что английское слово "tooth" (зуб) схоже с казахским "тiс" (произносится "тс" - зуб); "belt" (пояс, ремень) - в казахском "белдiк" (белтк - пояс, ремень - от "бел" - поясница, дiк - суффикс)- подобных совпадений множество, особенно в немецком и английском, поэтому напрашивается мысль что это не просто совпадения.
Всем огромное спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 0):

Атас это от якутского слова Атас, что дословно означает Товарищ. Человек стоящий на шухере, т.е. смотрящий как бы кто нибудь не подошёл, в минуту опасности кричит: "Атас", т.е. предупреждает товарища по совершению преступления словом " Товарищ ".